# Get Latest Order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing:

```
order ID, Order Date, Product Code, CustomerCode
```

From this table, I wanted to get for each order, for each product and customer code, O need to find:

- a. No of occurrence matching Product Code and Customer Code
- b. Check whether the record is the latest order (Yes / No)

Can someone please help me to get the SQL Server query to get this information?

```
ID  Date       ProdCode CustomerCode    No of Occurrence    Latest Order
1   02/01/2020  AC110   15004                2                   N
2   03/02/2020  AC114   15100                2                   N
3   03/02/2020  AC110   15004                2                   Y
4   05/03/2020  AC115   15610                1                   Y
5   06/04/2020  AC114   15100                2                   Y
6   06/04/2020  AC116   15209                1                   Y
7   06/04/2020  AC116   15620                1                   Y
```

Comment: SO is not free-coding service. Please, show us your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: You shared your sample result as a table. In order to get quick and accurate answers, it would better to share sample base data that you had used to get that result.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUB Query` to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
ID INT, [Date] DATE,       ProdCode VARCHAR(50), CustomerCode  VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1,'02/01/2020','AC110','15004')        
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2,'03/02/2020','AC114','15100')        
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3,'03/02/2020','AC110','15004')        
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(4,'05/03/2020','AC115','15610')        
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(5,'06/04/2020','AC114','15100')        
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(6,'06/04/2020','AC116','15209')        
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(7,'06/04/2020','AC116','15620')
```

Main Query:

```
select M.ID,M.Date,M.CustomerCode,M.ProdCode,S.NO_OF_OCCUR,CASE WHEN S.Latest_Date =M.Date THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Latest_Date
from @T M
INNER JOIN(
select COUNT(*) as NO_OF_OCCUR,MAX(Date) as Latest_Date, ProdCode,CustomerCode FROM @T
GROUP BY ProdCode,CustomerCode) S ON S.ProdCode=M.ProdCode AND 
S.CustomerCode=M.CustomerCode
```

Comment: It was great and helped. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows functions to compute the extra columns. For example:

```
select
  id,
  date,
  prodcode,
  customercode,
  occurence,
  case when rn = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as latestorder
from (
  select *,
    count(*) over(partition by customercode) as occurrence,
    row_number() over(partition by customercode desc) as rn
  from t
) x
```